# How to make equivalent encryption? (java, C#)

Tags: java, c#, encryption

Our C# version of this seemingly simple and standard java RSA encryption code is NOT generating the same result.  Help?

NOTE: the java code uses a DER file, so we had to firstly convert it to PEM format (via openssl)

- openssl rsa -inform DER -outform PEM -in FOO.der -out FOO.pem

and then that to XML (via BouncyCastle).  Specifically:

- using (var reader = new StreamReader(PrivateKeyPemFile)) { text =
  reader.ReadToEnd(); } string xmlpem = RsaKeyConverter.PemToXml(text);

What are we doing wrong here?  (Was it our key conversion?  Or is there a CspParameter setting that will magically make this equivalent?  Or...)

JAVA code

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyRawBytes);
java.security.Key key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(1, key);
encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

C# code

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
cryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(pemXmlString);
var encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(data, false);
```

Comment: Make sure you use the same character encoding in Java and C#.

Comment: You will get a different ciphertext every time that you encrypt the same plaintext due to padding.